# Transpose from long file to wide file using linux commands (awk)

Tags: shell, awk

I have a long file and I need a wide file, I know do that in R, but I want to do using Linux because is faster. The field separator is tab.

Input file

```
 1  C C
 1  G G     
 1  C G    
 2  G G    
 2  C C 
 2  C G  
 3  G G    
 3  C C    
 3  C C
```

Output file:

```
 1 2 3 
 CC GG GG
 GG GG CC
 CG CG CC
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming consistent data (same number of elements for each key)

```
$ awk '{k[$1]; a[$1,++c[$1]]=$2$3} 
    END{for(x in k) printf "%s",x OFS; 
        print ""; 
        for(i=1;i<=c[$1];i++) 
           {for(x in k) printf "%s", a[x,i] OFS; 
            print ""}}' file

1 2 3
CC GG GG
GG CC CC
CG CG CC
```

the order of columns not guaranteed though...